# min () expected sequence error only happens for newly created objects in edit mode

Tags: python, scripting

I wrote a script that selects the selected object's vertices with the lower Z value, and set's the origin of the object to the median point.
Everything worked perfectly until I tried to make things a bit better, by returning the 3D view mode to the mode that was used before running the script as in Edit Mode or Object Mode... etc.

The error I'm getting happens in a very specific case, and I couldn't find no logical explanation to it. I have "New Object in Edit Mode" enabled in my user preferences, so when I create a new object and run this scrip immediately, I'm getting an error:

`min() arg is an empty sequence`

- This error only occurs when an new object is created in Edit Mode, then I run the script immediately.
- I tried disabling creating new object in Edit Mode, the error disappeared!
- Even if create new object in Edit Mode is enabled, the error wont occur if I press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go to Object Mode first, then <kbd>tab</kbd> again to go back to Edit Mode, then run the script.
- This error will not occur in any other cases whether run in Object Mode or Edit Mode.
- I tried saving right after creating a new object in Edit Mode, then run the script, no error!
  This is a very weird situation to the programming novice me, so what am I doing wrong here? help appreciated in advance, blend file attached.
  **Edit:** I found a solution by unchecking "create in edit mode" off in user preferences, then checking it back after applying the rest of the code in the example, but I want to understand why is this error happening.

  [image]

Comment: (Without having downloaded and checked file) You are passing an empty list to `min(...)`  Either check for it, or use `min(sequence, default=0)` to return 0 when the list is empty.

Comment: Nope, this didn't solve the problem, first I tried it as is, but I got an Error "Sequence undefined", then I put it in quotation 'sequence', so I'm back to square 1, same error @batFINGER

Comment: It will need to be the name of the list (sequence) in the min function in *your* code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *lower z values* @Georges? The lower part of a mesh? What if the object is more complex geometry than any simple cube? Can you elaborate? Any use case?

Comment: @poor, it would work for complex mesh, but this is not what the question is about, it's about an error in a very specific case, plz check .blend

Comment: Huh, then you should read batFINGER's comment again. In other words: [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) is a function and expects an *iterable* e.g. a list as argument so if you are passing an *empty list* the error comes up. I've tested your script and can't reproduce your described behavior (I guess some lines are missing, right?) In my tests, the error message only appears in case the object itself contains no vertex (which is the expected behavior). Nevertheless the script sometimes works and sometimes it does not, one reason why I asked for your goal...

Comment: Then why it works in all cases except when "create new object in edit mode" is enabled in User Preferences?? Why is min() not having an expected argument error except in this specific case? That's my question

Comment: try going to User Preferences > Editing > New Objects: then check Enter Edit Mode, this is when things start to go wrong

Comment: batFinger's comment could be the right answer, but as I explained I'm a programming noob, it didn't really provide me an answer, if I was a seasoned programmer, most probably I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place :)

Comment: You need to update your edits if you are not using bmesh.
Add these to lines first to your def:

if bpy.context.object.mode == "EDIT":

        bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode()

Comment: @JuhaW this is perfect, this is what I was looking for, it eliminated the error, I've been enhancing the script during the past week, I managed to eliminate the error, but still wouldn't work from the first time, but this just solved everything like magic!!! Thank you!! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your edits if you are not using bmesh. Add these lines first to your def:

```
if bpy.context.object.mode == "EDIT":
    bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode()
```